# Command line XML validator that doesn't read the whole XML file into memory?

Tags: memory, command-line-interface, xml

I have an XML file that's 6.7GB *compressed*. I want to check this is valid XML from the command line. I tried using `xmlstarlet` and `xmllint` but the both balloned in memory.

Is there some sort of stream  XML validator for linux I can run on the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `xmllint --stream`?